# Prove $\bar{S}$ is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am new to set theory and I am struggling with this proof. I know that I need to show that $\bar{S}^c$ is open to show that $\bar{S}$ is closed.

I know that $\bar{S}=S\cup \partial S$.

Also, I know that $\partial S$ means that for all $x\in S$, $N_\epsilon(x)\cap \bar{S}\neq \emptyset$ and $N_\epsilon(x)\cap \bar{S}^c\neq \emptyset$.

I would appreciate some direction in putting this together. I know intuitively why its closed but I want to prove it using the definitions.

Open - For each $x$ in $U$ there is an epsilon $\epsilon > 0$ such that the interval $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$ is contained in $U$.

Closed - The complement is open.

Closed - every Cauchy sequence of elements in $S$ has a limit which is also an element of $S$.

Comment: If you define $\overline{S}=S\cup\partial S$, then you should not use $\overline{S}$ in order to define $\partial S$, right? Do you know any other definition of closure?

Comment: The definitions for "*open set, closed set, boundary...*" can differ from author to author and even from textbook to textbook. May you provide your definition so that we may help you better?

Comment: That's a very good point. I didn't think of that... I don't know any other definitions no... I just looked through my book and that's all I was given I think...

Comment: @CaveJohnson yes I will add that shortly.

Comment: Also, letting us know what context this question is in will help. With the notation $N_\epsilon(x)$, I'm assuming we're talking metric spaces or just $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology?

Comment: $N_\epsilon(x)$ is the interval (x-epsilon,x+epsilon) and is the neighborhood around x.

Comment: You can define $\partial S$ as the set of points $x$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap S\ne\emptyset\ne (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap (\mathbb{R}\setminus S)$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. Now, you may try to prove that $\overline{S}$ is closed by showing that its complement is open.

Comment: "complement", not "compliment".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Notes:

Suppose we're working in the context $S \subseteq \mathbb X$. You may define $\partial S$ as the $s \in \mathbb X$ such that $N_\epsilon(s)$ intersects both $S$ and $S^c$.

Note: **not $\overline S$ and $\overline{S}^c$** as you have said, although I believe this is also correct. But to avoid a circular definition as pointed out in the comments, you should avoid using the closure of $S$ in the definition of $\partial S$.

Also note that an equivalent notion of openness is that a set $C$ is open iff it contains *no boundary points* ($C \cap \partial C = \emptyset$). I find this more intuitive, so I'll use this definition in the following proof.

---

## Proof

You use the definition
$$\overline S = S \cup \partial S\; .$$
where $\partial S$ is defined as above.

By defining $\overline S$ in this way, we are including all boundary points of $S$. So the complement $\overline{S}^c$ *explicitly excludes these boundary points*. It looks from this as though $\overline{S}^c$ is not going to have any boundary points and will hence be open. However, it's not immediately obvious that $\overline{S}$ doesn't have boundary points of its own that are not in $\partial S$ (although it is true, resulting in closure being idempotent). So we will compute the complement of $\overline{S}$ explicitly:

$$\begin{align*}\overline{S}^c &= (S \cup \partial S)^c \\
&= S^c \cap (\partial S)^c \\
&=S^c -\partial S\end{align*}$$

If you give it some thought, it is a straightforward consequence of the definition of $\partial S$, as I stated at the top, that $\partial S = \partial (S^c)$. Consequently, $\overline{S}^c = S^c - \partial (S^c)$. In other words, it's equal to some set *with all boundary points of that set removed*. It hence has no boundary points, and is open.

Thus $\overline S$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $$\bar S^c = (S\cup\partial S)^c = S^c\cap (\partial S)^c, $$
so if $p\in \bar S^c$, $p\notin S$ and $p\notin \partial S$. Since $p\in S^c$, trivially any neighborhood of $p$ intersects $S^c$, so by definition of $\partial S$, there must exist a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ with $U\cap S=\varnothing$. This means that $p$ is an interior point of $S^c$, so that $S^c$ is open and hence $S$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Since the definition of closure that you know is $\overline{S}=S\cup \partial S$,  let's first define $\partial S$ without mentioning $\overline{S}$. Let $\partial S$ be the set of all $x$ such that for any $\varepsilon>0$ $$(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap S\ne\emptyset\ne (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap S^c.$$

Now, in order to prove that $\overline{S}$ is closed, we need to show that $\overline{S}^c$ is open, so we take a point $x\in \overline{S}^c$ and obtain an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset \overline{S}^c$.

Since $x\not\in S\cup \partial S$, it follows that $x\not\in S$ and $x\not\in \partial S$, meaning that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap S=\emptyset$ or $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap S^c=\emptyset$.

Note that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap S^c=\emptyset$ cannot happen (why?), hence $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap S=\emptyset$, implying that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset S^c$. It's not hard to see that if $y\in (x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$, then $y\not\in S\cup \partial S$, showing that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subset\overline{S}^c$, as desired.